# About Powerbi Embedded Reports Scheduled Refresh

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are planning to publish our powerbi reports in our sub-domain as a product for our customers. Our reports are refreshing on scheduled manner as new data arrives; hourly, daily, or per 3 hours (or live) etc. We initially tried to use 'publish to web' option, but we realise there is about one hour to see updates on published reports. We need it to be updated as scheduled update occurs.

We are considering to use embedded reports, but we could not find too much any information about how it refreshes. (we are using mysql as datasource for most of our reports)

Can we use embedded reports for that aim? Would it be refreshed instantly as we scheduled refresh our dataset/reports? Or are there any seperate methodology for refreshing embedded reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power BI Embedded reports' data refresh is subject to how you define the refresh policy in Power BI. You can define a **Scheduled Refresh** (up to a limit defined by your capacity) or you can trigger a **Refresh Now** API call as described here:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/

As for the report's data, once the dataset is refreshed, any new render of the report would show the updated data. 
If during the same session, you'd want to refresh the view of the report (by knowing that it has newer data) you can always call the Javascript SDK's `report.refresh()` call on the report.
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding---Basic-interactions#refresh-a-report

Comment: thanks for your answer. so we can set up 'scheduled refresh' as normal reports, from data gateway. after that when we get report from javascript SDK (or call reports.refresh() as you call), it'll have updated data, is it correct? i am confused since we are using mysql as data source, not direct query, and there were some unresolved questions (from 2016) about this on powerbi community forum.

Comment: @ayyayyekokojambo you are correct. Scheduled refresh refreshes the dataset (created in powerbi query cache using your mysql data source) and it is used across all powerbi service and embedded app

Comment: @RBreuer "any new render of the report would show the updated data"  This does not seem to be the case.  I have a web published report that just displays the old data even though the dataset has been refreshed in Power BI Service.  It shows different (older) data to the same report in Power BI Service.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer my article which explains about the data-set refresh manually and also using the WebAPI services
https://snkrishnan1.wordpress.com/2018/07/07/powerbi-dataset-refresh-using-net-webapi-service/